# std::next_permutation missing one entry

Tags: c++, stl

Following program is missing one permutation entry.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<int> temp;
    temp.push_back(10);
    temp.push_back(2);
    temp.push_back(4);
    temp.push_back(4);

    do {
        std::copy(temp.begin(),temp.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }while ( std::next_permutation (temp.begin(), temp.end()));
}
```

Following is the output of the program

```
10 2 4 4
10 4 2 4
10 4 4 2
```

why it is missing one entry which is

`2 4 4 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because that permutation is the first ordering for the list of number that you have.
You would need to sort the original array, then this permutation will be listed as the very first one.

```
std::vector<int> temp;
temp.push_back(10);
temp.push_back(2);
temp.push_back(4);
temp.push_back(4);
std::sort(temp.begin(),temp.end() );
```

Alternatively, you could just push the elements in sorted order, but for practical purposes, you should always sort if you want to generate all possible permutations.

Comment: Another option is to calculate how many permutations there should be using the appropriate math formulas, and then just iterate that many times, ignoring the return value from next_permutation.

Comment: you shouldn't sort the container if you _know_ it's already sorted.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it's probably not trivial to do, because of integer overflows.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: The code is trivial enough but surely not advisable, since as wilhelmtell mentioned there will be integer overflow. Then again, if integer overflow does occur, generating all those permutations on a Home PC (and most other systems out there) will be a very slow process.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz On further reflection, it's quite possible for integer overflow to be an annoying problem even if the total number of permutations turns out to be fairly small. Imagine for example taking a naive approach to the calculation, when you have 98 copies of 'a', 1 of 'b' and 1 of 'c' to permute... :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Yes, getting the right code for this can be annoying and a different discussion on it's own right ;).

Answer (score 1):

It's actually missing a few other valid permutations: `2 10 4 4` and `2 4 10 4`, and `4 4 10 2` for example.

As to why they are missing: it says, right there in the documentation:

> Return value
>   `true` if the function could rearrange the object as a lexicographically greater permutation. Otherwise, the function returns false to indicate that the arrangement is not greater than the previous, but the lowest possible (sorted in ascending order).

So the `while` loop ends after `10 4 4 2`, because that is the lexicographically greatest permutation (the one that's "biggest" when you compare them left-to-right, i.e. the one that's in descending order). After printing that one, next_permutation fails to get to the 'next' permutation, and wraps around to the "beginning" permutation of `2 4 4 10`; but that is not printed because the function also returned false.